# MediaWiki filepath Magic Word doesn't work for some files types

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to use the [MediaWiki `filepath` magic word](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#URL_data)` so that I can create some template links that pass a specific MediaWiki file.  Unfortunately with certain file types, filepath just returns nothing.

The file I'm trying to get the path for that's failing is a text file in this case.  I have confirmed that I am using the correct filename as I can create a regular file link using `[[File:Name.txt]]`, and `{{filepath:Image.png}}` works properly.

Example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
[http://server/processfile.php?path={{filepath:<filename>}} Process A File]
```

Is this a known issue?  Is there an easy way that I can debug what's happening here?

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: No, sorry, this is with an internal wiki that I can't link to publically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around a bunch more I was able to resolve the issue.  It turns out that even though the MediaWiki would accept the file, it was being assigned a random mime type because it was a .yaml file.

After updating `mime.types` and `mime.info` in MediaWiki and adding the mime type (`text/yaml`) to my IIS configuration, I was able to get the downloads working and the file links showing up.

**Full disclosure:** I *may* have been using an incorrectly cased file name even though I said that I was using the correct file name. :P

Comment: Not related to this q: please make sure to remove "thank you notes" if you decide to edit posts. Search for "fluff remove" on meta for more info. -Comment based on this edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15697924

Comment: Check.  I will make sure to do so in the future.